# Ingressgateway returns a status code different from Pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I install Istio on GKE and run the application.

Although there is no problem when accessing with curl, Ingressgateway returns a status code different from the status code of Pod's proxy by some image request when accessing from the browser. Specifically, 200 and 302 etc. are returned as 500 or 504. Resources to become 500 or 504 differ every time, but it is 1 or 2 out of about 100 image requests. And if you request another 500 or 504 request again, the correct response will come back without problems.

Do you know what is causing this kind of reason?

The environment is like this.
GKE 1.10.11-gke.1
Istio 1.0.4

```
helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set tracing.enabled=true --set kiali.enabled=true  --set global.proxy.includeIPRanges="10.0.0.0/8"
```

Below is the log obtained from Stackdriver Logging.

Ingressgateway log.

```
"[2019-01-22T09:16:17.048Z] \"GET /my/app/image.pngHTTP/2\" 504 UT 0 24 60001 - \"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36\" \"c0abe3be-1153-45c5-bd8e-067ab597feb4\" \"my.app.com\" \"10.128.0.116:80\" outbound|80|ga|myapp.default.svc.cluster.local - 10.128.0.16:443 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:62257\n"
```

Application Pod's istio-proxy log.

```
"[2019-01-22T09:16:17.048Z] \"GET /my/spp/images.pngHTTP/1.1\" 200 - 0 3113 0 0 \"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36\" \"c0abe3be-1153-45c5-bd8e-067ab597feb4\" \"my.app.com\" \"127.0.0.1:80\" inbound|80||myapp.default.svc.cluster.local - 10.128.0.116:80 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0\n"
```

nginx log.

```
{
  "uri": "/my/app/image.png",
  "host": "my.app.com",
  "requestTime": "0.000",
  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
  "xForwardedProto": "https",
  "user": "",
  "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
  "bodyByteSize": "3113",
  "method": "GET",
  "remoteAddress": "127.0.0.1",
  "upstreamResponseTime": "",
  "request": "GET /my/app/images.png HTTP/1.1",
  "referrer": "https://my.app.com/",
  "status": "200",
  "xForwardedFor": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
}
```

Looking at this log I think that Ingressgateway is dropping the response from Pod.

Answer (score 1):

`UT` in the [proxy's log](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/access_log#config-access-log) means that a timeout occurred:

> UT: Upstream request timeout in addition to 504 response code.

Try to increase connection timeout by specifying [Connection Pool Settings](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#ConnectionPoolSettings) in a [Destination Rule](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#DestinationRule):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  host: myapp.default.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      tcp:
        connectTimeout: 10s
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not solve it. 504 is returned after the timeout specified by VirtualService has elapsed. Even if you set a time longer than the timeout specified in VirtualService.

Comment: So what is the timeout in your VirtualService?

Comment: It is 60 seconds. It will be 504 from the browser after 60 seconds from the request.

Comment: Can you increase both, e.g. to 600s. How much time downloading that file should take?

Comment: Even in 600 seconds it got 504 after 600 seconds from access. When curl or browser is `my.app.com/my/app/image.png` it will be 200, but when accessed by `css` of `my.app.com/top` it will be 504. `/top` has access to about 150 to 180 images, 1 or 2 of them fails to 504, and the rest succeeds in 200. I access images with `http2`.

Comment: So can you try some ridiculously large number, like 1000000s?

Comment: I have accessed it to 1000000 now. Pod's istio-proxy immediately output 200 logs but Ingressgateway's log has not been output yet. I think that is because it is connected with the browser.

Comment: Does anyone have a clue about the 500 from Envoy mentioned above? We are experiencing a similar issue, but the only thing that I could find about 500 from Envoy is if you reach a response body buffer limit, which we observe in a health endpoint where the body is very small.